# Flutter 3 Column grid with grid widget

Tags: flutter

I am Flutter beginner, Trying to create a page which has 3 column grid which spans to multiple rows (basically should wrap to next line if more than 3 items). [![enter image description here][1]][1]. As you see in the design there are other widgets in the screen. I tried with Grid Widget but it scrolls within the widget container, I don't want an internal scroll, but it should scroll with the page.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: List.generate(7, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Item $index',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must set `primary: false` in your gridview:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  children: List.generate(7, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Item $index',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
      ),
    );
  }),
);
}
```

For more info: [check docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/primary.html)